# What terms should be better to set when creating a Startup with your PhD supervisor?

Tags: phd, advisor, professorship

What terms should be better to set when creating a Startup with your PhD supervisor?

I had the PhD project idea before starting the PhD and working on it for some years. Now my PhD research looks promising for commercial use and I am thinking to create a startup. I recognize the prestige of my PhD supervisor and he is willing to participate in the startup.

Which are considered fair terms for both me and the professor for our new startup, based on the fact that i have done all the development (spending countless hours of work the past years) and came up with the project idea, but the professor has the prestigious name to make the startup more credible (and maybe better funded)?

Share equal equity? Have equity based on hours spent on the startup? Something else?

Comment: 25% to the supervisor as in the famous Seinfeld episode. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34MdFOHlQKY

Comment: Check your university policy.  Very probably your university already owns your work.

Comment: as answered below, no, the phd work IP is owned by the phd student and professor-supervisor at my university

Answer (score 4):

I strongly suggest that you hire a lawyer to get this advice. Failing to do so could lead to a huge amount of conflict later. It is likely that your interests don't completely align with those of your advisor.

I'm not a lawyer so can't help much, but it might be possible to set up a joint meeting with a lawyer and the advisor to work out an equitable arrangement. Your joint venture will need legal advice in any case.

But you also need to consider what a conflict would mean for finishing your degree. Don't put that in jeopardy.

Comment: The university might have an interest in or a policy on this intellectual property.

Comment: @EthanBolker, ah, yes. And they probably have lawyers (big universities anyway).

Comment: You don't need a lawyer to negotiate with your co-founder unless it's adversarial and if it's adversarial at this stage just give up because it's never going to work. Get the lawyer involved later to make sure your term sheets are written right. (The university's lawyers aren't yours).

Comment: @Libor, there is a built in imbalance of power between student and advisor. There have been other questions here about abuse in such situations. And, hiring a lawyer for advice isn't the same as starting a suit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. No, my university rule is that IP of PhD is student's and professor's, not university's. And also I guess lawyer for advice is different from suit..
Should this happen from day 0, or its better to ask for lawyer when this start to get more serious? (like taking a fund)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to think about if you're considering spinning up a startup. The skill set you're going to need and the skill set you currently have do not overlap. There are things you can do to fix this - if you're at a school with an established tech transfer pipeline they'll likely have seminars on a regular basis. Start going to them. All of them.

Intellectual property is very important. If you don't know how patents work and have never read one, now's the time to start learning.

I'm going to give you some links to a panel series that's very good as a primer, but you need to find the resources and people to help you learn this stuff. A lawyer is useless for you because you have no idea what you're doing or what you want yet. The lawyer makes sure you're doing it correctly and legally - what ***it*** is you're doing is *your problem*.

https://techventures.columbia.edu/entrepreneur-and-vc-perspectives-intellectual-property

https://techventures.columbia.edu/term-sheet-recommendations-for-launching-university-startups

https://techventures.columbia.edu/recommended-process-improvements-for-launching-university-startups

Answer (score -1):

I was curious about this, universities like to attempt to take IP if it's related to your formal thesis/project/what-ever.

You need to be careful that nothing you do that you want to sell is developed on university property.

The advantage of course is that the university may "help" you but the problem is they basically completely own it.

Comment: phd work IP is owned by me and the professor. I dont have worries about this..